# posting json parameter to api use post method Swift 3

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, swift3, http-post

I need to pass the following json to this function so Shopify Api can understand the submission. I am unable to create the correct variable format and pass it to server.Shopify API is expecting the following json to be passed via POST

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace REQUEST_URL with your API URL

Replace JSON_STRING with your actual json string

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "REQUEST_URL")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "JSON_STRING" 
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
    print("error=\(error)")
    return
}

if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
    print("response = \(response)")
}

let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
   print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

convert your object into dictionary and then serialize it by

```
   do{
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])
        postString = String.init(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: parth can u tell me how to set my json string inside 'let poststring = "Json_strong" ??

Comment: do you have json String of your data or objects?

Comment: objects parth brother

Comment: then you can convert your objects into dicitionary form and then serialize using json serialization